# Is this pronunciation transcript understandable for people who know British English?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, spelling-pronunciations, pronunciation-respelling

I wonder how to write down the pronunciation of words in English without using IPA. Sometimes on the internet I have seen something like this:

> It is pronounced like uh-aw-to-muh-tuh

Or

> It is pronounced like pruh-nuhn-see-ey-shuhn

Some examples of the use of this notation:

https://www.reddit.com/r/eurovision/comments/lzgzu9/how_to_pronounce_m%C3%A5neskin/
https://www.reddit.com/r/FantasyPL/comments/9ocjb6/how_to_pronounce_doherty/
https://www.reddit.com/r/brandonsanderson/comments/2xvtn7/how_to_pronounce_raoden/
https://www.reddit.com/r/HannibalTV/comments/2268nz/how_to_pronounce_mads_mikkelsen_2_danish_audio/

Searching on google I found this:

Vowels

- a as in hat
- aa as in father
- arr as in marry
- ar as in bar
- air as in hair
- aw as in law
- ay as in day
- e as in get
- err as in merry
- ee as in meet
- eer as in deer
- i as in sit
- irr as in mirror
- o as in top
- orr as in sorry
- oh as in no
- oo as in boot
- oor as in poor
- or as in corn
- ow as in now
- oy as in boy
- u as in cup
- uh as in ago / the
- ur as in fur
- urr as in hurry
- uu as in book
- y as in cry (also igh as in high)
- oe as in French peu or coeur
- oey as in French fauteuil
- ue as in French vu or German fünf

Consonants

- b as in bat
- ch or tch as in church
- d as in day
- f as in fat
- g as in get
- h as in hat
- hl as in Welsh llan
- j as in Jack
- k as in king
- kh as in Scottish loch or German ich
- l as in leg
- m as in man
- n as in not
- ng as in sing
- ng-g as in finger
- nk as in thank
- p as in pen
- r as in red
- s as in sit
- sh as in shop
- t as in top
- th as in thin
- dh as in there
- v as in van
- w as in will
- y as in yes
- z as in zebra
- zh as in measure

Is this way universally understood at least in the UK? Of course, without using "as in x"

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137005/discussion-on-question-by-donterioo-is-this-pronunciation-transcript-understanda).